# Maximizing a bivariate quadratic form with Lagrange's method

Tags: optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, lagrange-multiplier, non-convex-optimization, qcqp

> Maximize the generic bivariate quadratic form constrained to the unit circle.
>
> $$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & f(x_1, x_2) := ax_1^2 + 2bx_1 x_2 + cx_2^2\\ \text{subject to} & g(x_1, x_2) := x_1^2 + x_2^2 - 1 = 0\end{array}$$

Using the standard Lagrange Method with the Lagrange multiplier $\lambda$, we have:

\begin{align*}
  \nabla f &= \lambda \nabla g \\
  f_x &= \lambda g_x \\
  f_y &= \lambda g_y \\
  a x_1 + b x_2 &= \lambda x_1 \\
  b x_1 + c x_2 &= \lambda x_2 \\
\end{align*}

This translates to solving for eigenvalues and eigenvectors for

\begin{align*}
  A &= \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ b & c \end{pmatrix} \\
  Ax &= \lambda x \\
\end{align*}

The maximum and minimum coordinates of $f(x_1, x_2)$ are the eigenvectors that are scaled to fit on the unit circle. My textbook states the following:

> Show that the maximum and minimum values of $f(x_1, x_2)$ are the eigenvalues themselves.

But is it true? Can someone demonstrate that?

Comment: Must you use Lagrange multipliers? There is an easier way.

Comment: I wasn't solving this problem for its own sake, I was trying to understand a textbook section that used that as an example to build into something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiply the Lagrange conditions as follows:
\begin{align}
x_1 \times (a x_1 + b x_2 = \lambda x_1)\\
x_2 \times (b x_1 + c x_2 = \lambda x_2)\\
\end{align}
and sum them up. Now use the fact that $(x_1,x_2)$ is on the unit circle and you would easily get: $f(x_1,x_2) = a x_1^2 + 2bx_1x_2 + cx_2^2 = \lambda$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=(x_1,x_2)$ such that $x_1^2+x_2^2=1$ and

$f(x)=\max \{f(u,v):u^2+v^2=1\}$. By Lagrange there is $ \lambda \in \mathbb R$ such that $Ax=\lambda x$.Hence

$\lambda= \lambda x^Tx=x^T(Ax)=f(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be easily solved without the Lagrange multipliers

Make the transformation

$$
x_1 = \cos\theta\\
x_2 = \sin\theta
$$

then the objective function will read

$$
f(\theta) = a \cos^2\theta + 2 b \sin \theta\cos\theta + c \sin^2\theta
$$

and now the stationary points are obtained by solving

$$
\frac{df}{d\theta} = 2b\cos(2\theta)+(c-a)\sin(2\theta) = 0 \Rightarrow \theta = \frac{1}{2}\arctan\left(\frac{2b}{a-c}\right)
$$

etc.